# is 1.5V accepted tolerance for amplifier power supply

Tags: voltage, power

I have A200 Creative speakers with 10.5 V, 1 A transformer which not working, and i can buy 12V-1A transformer only. Is 1.5 V accepted tolerance for the amplifier power supply?

Comment: Removing the capital 'I' from the title does not make this a better question.

Comment: @Transistor  my question is very  straight forward , i don't know what else you want to know !

Comment: I'm just wondering why you un-corrected the capitalisation correction I had made to the title (and others). It's wrong now. Apart from that your question has been closed as a duplicate. If the linked answer doesn't solve your problem then you need a major edit to clarify what's different or what you don't understand. You haven't supplied a link to the datasheet for the A200 either so you're expecting us to look it up. Your edit will need to be good to get the question reopened.